# Windowing in React/Gatsby/Chakra UI

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, chakra-ui

I have a simple web app using React, Gatsby and Chakra UI frameworks. The app consists of an index page which queries frontmatter from 1000+ mdx files and renders a minimal summary component with 5 fields from the frontmatter and a link to a detail page for each.  The 1000+ detail pages are generated in gatsby-node.js using createPage.

The index page uses map to iterate through each of the mdx nodes and uses a Chakra UI simple grid along with some other Chakra components for each item.

The lighthouse report received when the app is deployed to Gatsby Cloud rates the app 60/100 for performance largely due to excessive elements in the DOM (the 1000+ summary elements rendered by the index page).

I’ve reviewed all of the related documentation and searched SO among other sources but can find no feasible solution to rendering only the html for the 25 or so items that are displayed on screen at any given point and rendering the rest as needed rather than rendering all 1000+ from the outset.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { ChakraProvider, chakra, Box, SimpleGrid, HStack, Button, VStack, Wrap, WrapItem, Badge } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { graphql, useStaticQuery } from 'gatsby';

const IndexPage = () => {

    const query = useStaticQuery(graphql` 
    query AllObjects {
      allMdx(sort: {fields: frontmatter___field1}) {
        nodes {
          frontmatter {
            field1
            field2
            field3
            field4
            field5
            field6
            field7
            uniqueId
          }
        }
      }
    }
    `)

    return (
      <ChakraProvider>
        <body>
            <main>
                      <SimpleGrid columns={{base: 1, lg: 3, md: 2, sm:1}} spacing={{base: '1.5em', lg: '1.5em', md:'1.0', sm:'0.90em'}}>
                      { query.allMdx.nodes.map((node) => (
                          <Box key={node.frontmatter.field1} margin="2em" padding="1em">
                            <HStack padding="0.4em" align="center" alignItems="stretch" justifyContent="space-between">
                            <Button size="sm" shadow="md" colorScheme="blue"
                            onClick={(e) => {
                              e.preventDefault();
                              window.location.href=`/objects/${node.frontmatter.field1.toLowerCase()}`;
                              }}
                            >Detail</Button>
                            <Box align="center"/>
                            <VStack alignItems="end" justifyContent="right">
                            <Wrap columns={2} spacing={1} direction={["row-reverse"]} isInline="true" shouldWrapChildren="true">
                              <WrapItem>
                                {node.frontmatter.field5 === true &&
                                <Badge colorScheme="green">Field5</Badge>
                                }
                              </WrapItem>
                              <WrapItem>
                                {node.frontmatter.field6 === true &&
                                <Badge colorScheme="blue">Field6</Badge>
                                }
                              </WrapItem>
                              <WrapItem>
                                {node.frontmatter.field7 === true &&
                                <Badge colorScheme="orange">field7</Badge>
                                }
                              </WrapItem>
                              <WrapItem>
                                {node.frontmatter.field4 === true &&
                                <Badge colorScheme="red">Field8</Badge>
                                }
                              </WrapItem>
                            </Wrap>
                            </VStack>
                            </HStack>
                            <Box bg="gray.300" borderRadius="0.5em" margin="0em" padding="0em">
                            <chakra.h2 id={node.frontmatter.field1.toLowerCase()}>
                              Field1: {node.frontmatter.field1}
                            </chakra.h2>
                            <chakra.p>Field2: {node.frontmatter.field2}</chakra.p>
                            <chakra.p>{node.frontmatter.field3}</chakra.p>
                            </Box>
                          </Box>
                      ))}
                      </SimpleGrid>

            </main>
        </body>
      </ChakraProvider>
    )
  };

export default IndexPage;
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you spot the solution. Use an infinite scroll or some similar delayed (button, etc) approach to render the full amount of grid items on-demand, rather than all of them at the same time.

Just create a state (`useState`) that contains the sliced amount of elements and upgrade them as soon as the user scrolls the page. That will save (and delay) your initial DOM elements.

I will add a button-based approach to render more elements but the idea is exactly the same using an infinite scroll.

```
const IndexPage = () => {
    const query = useStaticQuery(graphql` 
    query AllObjects {
      allMdx(sort: {fields: frontmatter___field1}) {
        nodes {
          frontmatter {
            field1
            field2
            field3
            field4
            field5
            field6
            field7
            uniqueId
          }
        }
      }
    }
    `)
  // Array of all news articles
  const allGridElements = query.allMdx.nodes

  // State for the list
  const [list, setList] = useState([...allGridElements.slice(0, 10)])

  // State to trigger the load more
  const [loadMore, setLoadMore] = useState(false)

  // State of whether there is more to load
  const [hasMore, setHasMore] = useState(allGridElements.length > 10)

  // Load more button click
  const handleLoadMore = () => {
    setLoadMore(true)
  }

  // Handle loading more articles
  useEffect(() => {
    if (loadMore && hasMore) {
      const currentLength = list.length
      const isMore = currentLength < allGridElements.length
      const nextResults = isMore
        ? allGridElements.slice(currentLength, currentLength + 10)
        : []
      setList([...list, ...nextResults])
      setLoadMore(false)
    }
  }, [loadMore, hasMore]) //eslint-disable-line

  //Check if there is more
  useEffect(() => {
    const isMore = list.length < allGridElements.length
    setHasMore(isMore)
  }, [list]) //eslint-disable-line

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Load more demo</h1>
      <div>
        {list.map((item) => (
        { /* Your JSX rendering the grid items */ }
        ))}
      </div>
      {hasMore ? (
        <button onClick={handleLoadMore}>Load More</button>
      ) : (
        <p>No more results</p>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}

export default IndexPage
```

*Note: to avoid a neverending answer I omitted the JSX returned by your loop. Just place it in the comment.*

It's quite self explanatory, you set all your elements in a React state (`useState`) and iterate through it. The `useEffect` is in charge of upgrade the list based on a listener.

Other useful resources:

- https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-an-infinite-scroll-image-gallery-with-gatsby-and-netlify-functions
- https://www.gatsbyjs.com/starters/baobabKoodaa/gatsby-starter-infinite-scroll

Comment: That’s great, thanks! I’ll give that a go.